Electrostatic pressure for dielectric fluid
I am considering the following arrangement of a capacitor partially submerged in a dielectric fluid.

It can be shown that the capacitance of this arrangement is: $$C=\frac{2\pi\epsilon_0}{\ln(b/a)}(L-h+\epsilon h)$$
If a potential difference $V$ is applied, the height of the fluid will increase. A simple way to find this is to consider the total energy $$u=\frac{1}{2}CV^2+\frac{1}{2}\rho g\pi(b^2-a^2)x$$ and minimise for $x$, the height increase. It turns out that $$x=\dfrac{\epsilon_0(\epsilon-1)V^2}{g\rho(b^2-a^2)\ln(b/a)}$$
An alternative method would be to consider the electrostatic pressure $$P=\frac{1}{2}\bf{E}\cdot{D}$$ Then at a given radius $r$, there would be a pressure difference of $$\dfrac{Q^2}{8\pi^2\epsilon_0L^2r^2}(1-\epsilon)$$ for total charge $Q=CV$. Since the pressure difference has a dependence on $r$ how can the fluid level be horizontal? Can this method yield the same result as the first?

Related? Capacitor in a dielectric fluid

@Farcher Yes it's related but my question focuses on the using the electrostatic pressure explicitly.
